# How can I get less SQL request in my railsApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a RailsApp, especially on reduce the SQL request from my controller. A friend of mine told me about storing those data into a hash or array to reduce it. But I have some troubles to do it.

Here's what my controller looks like :

```
def count(var)
  var.count
end

def fb_connection(x)
  count_fb_sign_in = 0
  x.each do |user|
    count_fb_sign_in += 1 if user.facebook_token.present?
  end
  return count_fb_sign_in
end

def email_connection(x)
  count_sign_in = 0
  x.each do |user|
    count_sign_in += 1 unless user.facebook_token.present?
  end
  return count_sign_in
end

def sum_sign_in(x)
  x.sum(:sign_in_count)
end

def datetime_sign_in(x, y)
  x.where('last_sign_in_at >= ?', y).sum(:sign_in_count)
end

def bars_per_city(x)
  @places.where(region_id:x).count
end
```

Here's what I've tried so far but I don't know if it's the right/best way to do it :

```
def stats
  @user = User.all
  user_data = Hash.new
  user_data["User_sum] = @user.count
  user_data["user_email"] = @user.select(:facebook_token).count
  return user_data
end
```

When I tried this, I have some troubles to put in into my index.html.haml.

Does some of you have some leads ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should create instance variables inside the controller action which can be accessed in your view.  You have a method `def stats` which should be a private method unless it is a custom route.  If it is a method which would be used in multiple end points in your controller you might do add it as a before action:

```
before_action :stats, only: [:index]

def index
 @user = User.all
end

private

  def stats
    #create a hash and use symbolized keys (rails standard)
    @user_data = {
      user_sum: User.count,
      user_facebook_token_count: User.where.not(facebook_token: ['', nil]).count
    }
  end
```

You now have access to `@user_data` hash in your view so you could do:

```
.content
  = @user_data[:user_sum]
```

And you would also have access to `@users` in your view of course.

It also looks like you have a lot of methods which should probably be model methods and/or model scopes.  It's also bad practice to use cryptic variable names in your methods, but better to pass something which would indicate the data type the method is operating on.  For example:

```
# This looks like a User model method, and if so, you shouldn't need to pass anything
def fb_connection
  #This is much more efficient. In ruby you don't need explicit return
  #the value of the last method called gets returned.
  User.where.not(facebook_token: [nil, '']).count
end
```

But this again belongs in the model, and could be simply a class method

```
#user.rb
class User
  def self.fb_connection_count
    where.not(facebook_token: [nil, '']).count
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lacostenycoder, it's really helpful!

Comment: @RaphaëlFOSSE glad this helped.  I also updated my answer to use ActiveRecord query instead of select inside the controller method, which was what I had used in the model method anyway. It's more efficient then `.select`